# Fine Uploader 4.1.1 S3 getSize() returns 'undefined' in IE 9

Tags: fine-uploader

Following is client-side javascript code, part of fine-uploader initialization:

```
        key: function (fileId) {
            var keyRetrieval = new qq.Promise(),
                filename = encodeURIComponent(uploader.getName(fileId)),
                xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    var status = xhr.status,
                        key = xhr.responseText;

                    if (status !== 200) {
                        keyRetrieval.failure();
                    }
                    else {                            
                        keyRetrieval.success(eval('(' + key + ')').key);
                    }
                }
            }

            xhr.open("POST", "/getkey.ashx?name=" + filename + "&filesize=" + encodeURIComponent(uploader.getSize(fileId)));
            xhr.send();

            return keyRetrieval;
```

Firefox and chrome works. 
In IE 9, getName(fileId) method returns the filename, but getSize(fileId) returns 'undefined'

Any suggestions ? Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to lack of File API support, file size reporting in IE9 and older is not possible, so this  return type is expected.

Comment: Thanks Ray for reminder. While I remember reading about this somewhere on fine-uploader site. It would help others, if you add this note or link at API page ...  /api/methods.html#getSize

Comment: There is a mention of size reporting on the supported features by browser matrix at http://docs.fineuploader.com/browser-support.html.

Comment: Will I be able to use the above code without getSize() method in IE 9 or 8? I am not familiar with XHR2, is my code using XHR2 feature ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you should be able to.  XHR2 is not needed for a simple POST ajax request.  Note that a GET request is probably more appropriate than a POST in your case, unless your request will result in server-side changes.